# create table in plsql with user supplied table names

Tags: oracle, plsql

Requirement:-
create table 'new_table' as select * from 'existing_table';

I want to implement above query in a oracle Procedure and  I also want to make the procedure to take the user inputs for the 'new_table' and 'existing_table'.

basically I do not want to hardcode the create table statement inside procedure body.

Please suggest me and approach or solution for the above case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need [tag:dynamic-sql] for that

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure would look something like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_table (
    p_tab_name VARCHAR2,
    p_existing_tab VARCHAR2
)
    AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE '
                      || p_tab_name
                      || ' AS SELECT * FROM '
                      || p_existing_tab;
END;
/
```

You can then call the procedure like this to get user input:

```
BEGIN
   create_table('&tab_name','&existing');
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks Kaushik, It's working as expected.